# Any idea why my functions are not working?

Tags: python, function, addition

Trying to create a simple password generator but my functions arent giving me the intended result or outcome i want. I.e. not adding up to expand the empty list. Should i be changing anything?

```
import random

def passstrength():
    return input("Please state how strong you have the password to be? (1 = strongest, 2 = medium, 3 = weakest): ")

passstrength = passstrength()

list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','q','r','s','t','u','v','x','y','z']

list2 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','Q','R','S','T','U','V','X','Y','Z']

list3 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

list4 = ["@","$","%","&"]

r = []

def getpass(x):
    return random.sample(x,2)

def mergepass(first,second,third):
    if passstrength == 1:
        a = getpass(first)
        b = getpass(second)
        c = getpass(third)
        r = (a + b + c)
        return r
    elif passstrength == 2:
        a = getpass(first)
        b = getpass(second)
        r = (a + b)
        return r
    else:
        a = getpass(first)
        r = (a)
        return r

print (mergepass(list1,list2,list3))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`passstrength` is passed as a string so when you compare it to `int` it fails.

You can fix it by doing:

```
passstrength = int(passstrength())
```